# Why can't anonymous users make contributions?

Tags: contribution-page, permissions, pcp

I want anonymous users to be able to make online contributions (both through standard contribution pages and through PCP pages). I have the "make online contributions" selected in anonymous user role, but my site still requires a user to create an account (both on standard and PCPs).

Using latest CiviCRM and latest D7.

Comment: Okay, I can now edit the role (don't know why I couldn't before), but the basic problem remains: no one can make an online contribution without having a user account or creating one. This appears to be true for all my contribution pages.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what happens when an anonymous user tries to make a contribution.

Comment: Consider opening a new question, since the original problem is solved; otherwise you won't get the help you're looking for.  You'll also need to provide more detail with regard to error messages, etc.

Comment: similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7455/how-to-allow-contributions-from-non-members

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean an account is required to even fill in your page, or that filling in the page creates an account?

If the former then it sounds like a permission issue such as Anon not having access to the following

- CiviCRM: profile listings and forms
- CiviCRM: access all custom data.

These Permissions are usually part of default permissions afaik

Within the Profile settings you want to make sure that you have not set **Account creation required** which can be found in the advanced settings: **Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Profile**.