# How to allow contributions from non-members

Tags: civicontribute, drupal

This has got to be easy, but I am stumped.

I have set up several contribution pages. They work just fine as long as the donor is logged in to civi.

However, if the donor is not logged in, the system takes their credit card information on the form but when you press the contribute button, it blanks the form and does not continue on with the contribution process.

I **assume** that Civi allows unregistered users to contribute.

I am using Civi 4.6.9 on Drupal

Comment: v similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/why-cant-anonymous-users-make-contributions

Answer (score 2):

Within the Profile settings you want to make sure that you have not set **Account creation required** which can be found in the advanced settings: **Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Profile**.

By default, *for whatever bizarre reason*, the Supporter profile has **Account creation required** set as default. It took me a good hour to find that one!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the logs and post any messages?

Also double check the Drupal permissions so an anonymous user has "CiviContribute: make online contributions" permission.

Comment: Yes, CiviContribute: Make online contributions" is clicked on for anonymous users. Are there other permissions needed as well?

Comment: Possibly related to custom fields if you have added any to the profiles in the page. Did you check the logs?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the drupal error file. (There is an unserialize error) but it shows even when the contribution is successful (I.e., when user is logged in). Where would these error show up? In the drupal log report or in the Civi errors. When I turn off logging in Civi's Admin, I get no entries at all in the civi log files.    As for profile pages, I am not sure how to answer. I created a test donate page with no reference to any profiles and got the same error.