# Anonymous Users Cannot Contribute

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, contribution-page

I have set up a donation page linked to Paypal. (https://contacts.network211.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=6)

- When I attempt to use the contribution form as a non-logged in user, I enter my donation amount and email address. When I hit Confirm Contribution, ***the system returns to the contribution form with all fields empty.*** No error message or indication of what is going on.
- The contribution works if I am logged into civi as an authenticated user.

Settings

- I am not asking the user for any additional information, ie. not using a profile
- The form is set as active/online
- Under drupal permissions, I have CiviContribute: make online contributions selected
- I have looked in both Drupal and Civi logs and don't see anything that seems to point to the problem.

This is very frustrating!

(I asked the same question earlier with no resolution. [How to allow contributions from non-members](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7455/how-to-allow-contributions-from-non-members) This link also yields no answers [Why can't anonymous users make contributions?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/why-cant-anonymous-users-make-contributions))

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?  If you disable them one at a time to test, might that help?

Comment: Maybe it's something about your base url or resource url's is not set up quite right.  Also, do you have clean url set on the drupal side (https://www.contacts.network211.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls)?  I believe you should be able to replace the ? with a / in your link and have it still work, i.e. ...civicrm/contribute/transact/reset=1&id=6) .  It doesn't in your case.  (It does in my implimenation if clean url's are set.  If they're not set I get errors on the paypal site.)

Comment: @Paul-Tahoe: I'll try this, but it doesn't make sense in that civi never takes me to the confirm page (which is still on civi)

Comment: @AllenHutchison: I have no extension installed or at least none are checked under Civi in the drupal modules page

Comment: @KeithSorbo, for Civi specific extensions, you would want to look in your CiviCRM menu: Administer > System Settings > Manage Extensions and see if any extensions are enabled there.

Comment: @AllenHutchison: I had one extension (simpledonate). I disabled and uninstalled it. Same behavior. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @KeithSorbo, thanks for following up on that.  For the sake of trying to isolate the issue, if you create a paid event (just for testing purposes), can anonymous users sign up and try to pay for it?  Also, are you using Paypal Standard or Pro?

Comment: Also, do you have Drupal Watchdog Logging enabled?  (http://<site>/civicrm/admin/setting/debug?reset=1)  You could also enable backtrace on that same page and it might help pinpoint where the issue is coming from.  If you copy/paste your backtrace log (it'll appear on the page if there is an error happening) as an edit to your question, that'd help.

Comment: Lastly, can you screen print your Resource URLs screen (http://<site>/civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1) and add that to your question?  @Paul-Tahoe may have been on to something with his earlier comment - see https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=26696.msg114457#msg114457

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same issue on a new site I've just started working with. The contribution page works faultlessly when logged in, but does as Keuth describes when the user is not logged in. version 4.6.13 on D7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further investigation on my site, which was exhibiting the same issue as that noted by Keith Sorbo, showed that there was no 'user 0' record in the Drupal users table.

This page - https://www.drupal.org/node/1029506 - offers various options about how to reinstate a 'user 0' record in the Drupal database.

Once I had a 'user 0' record the CiviCRM contribution page worked as expected.